# BigQuery - Select only first row in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with data where in Column A I have groups of repeating Data (one after another).

I want to select only first row of each group based on values in column A only (no other criteria). Mind you, I want all corresponding columns selected also for the mentioned new found row (I don't want to exclude them).

Can someone help me with a proper query.

Here is a sample:
[SAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96giP.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share some sample data and what you have tried so far?

Comment: HI @BenP, I have added a picture of my sample data in Excel in comment (hence I don't know how to add it in comments :D ).  You can tell that in REFERENCE column, for example, in lines 2,3,4 I have the same data, and I only want the first row to show. Ive tried some queries but it didnt work for me. Furthermore, it is important for that selected row to have all correspoding columns as well.

Answer (score 11):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT row.*
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] row
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  GROUP BY columnA
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail. Do you have any idea of performance when compared to using an equivalent `row_number()` solution?

Answer (score 8):

you can try smth like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
   * EXCEPT(rn)
FROM (
   SELECT
   *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY columnA) AS rn
FROM
   your_dataset.your_table)
WHERE rn = 1
```

that will return:

```
Row   columnA       col2       ...   
1     AC1001        Z_Creation   
2     ACO112BISPIC  QN
...
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your help. This indeed works as you presented. However, I need this to work on the entire table, not only on the example I gave. Also, I need all present columns to show as well, as i stated in commentary and in my post.

Comment: So chose your table instead my example and select * EXCEPT(rn). Post edited

Answer (score 7):

Add `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query

something like

```
SELECT name, year FROM person_table ORDER BY year LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can now use `qualify` for a more concise solution:

```sql
select
   *
from
   your_dataset.your_table
where true
qualify ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY columnA) = 1
```

Comment: How does performance differ with QUALIFY vs windowing?

Comment: P.S. QUALIFY is still in a preview

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery the physical sequence of rows is not significant. “BigQuery does not guarantee a stable ordering of rows in a table. Only the result of a query with an explicit ORDER BY clause has well-defined ordering.”[[1]](https://books.google.es/books?id=LDaiAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

First, you need to define which property will determine the first row of your group, then you can run Vasily Bronsky’s query by changing ORDER BY with that property. Which means either you should add another column to the table to store the order of the rows or select one from the columns you have.